# unable to access the globalProperties - vuejs v3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, quasar-framework

My current project is on [Quasar framework](https://quasar.dev/) with [vuejs 2](https://vuejs.org/)

I have a file **/src/boot/gfunc.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.prototype.$module = 'foo';
```

in **/quasar.conf.js**

```
 boot: ['gfunc'],
```

in **/src/pages/Foo.vue**

```
beforeCreate : function () {
    console.log(this.$module);
}
```

Its working fine! and in the console I am able to see **foo**

Now I have used the [vuejs 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/) with [Quasar framework](https://quasar.dev/), and now **Vue.prototype**  replaced by **app.config.globalProperties** [[Doc]](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties)

**My Changes are as follow**

in **/src/boot/gfunc.js** as per  [[Doc]](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties)

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
const app = createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.$module = 'foo';
```

in **/quasar.conf.js**

```
 boot: ['gfunc'],
```

in **/src/pages/Foo.vue**

```
beforeCreate : function () {
    console.log(this.$module);
}
```

**Its Not working this time**, console printing **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. In my case is to access the axios. In v2 I accessed this way

```
this._vm.$http.get(url)
```

but now in v3 I don't know how to make teh same thing.

=========================

I solved my problem this way:

In my file where I created de app and create a app.config.globalProperties.$http variable, I put the http intance inside de store too. like this:

```
export default async ({ app, store }) => {
  // your logic

  app.config.globalProperties.$http = http
  store.$http = http
}
```

And in file that I used `this._vm.$http` , I use `this.$http`, without `_vm`.

I realy expect this help you.